# How to select tabs for tabless NSTabViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstabview, nstabviewcontroller

I have created sample `NSTabViewController` project.
I have added tab View Controller with 3 tab items. 
Then I have make tabview to tab less and switch tab with the help of three buttons.
I have take buttons actions in my main view controller.
I am selecting tabs using

```
[tabController setSelectedTabViewItemIndex:tag];
//tabController is NSTabController and Tag is selected tab index
```

Problem:Tab selection not changes with buttons.

[image: 1]]

```
SSTabViewController *tabController = (SSTabViewController*) [self getController:@"SSTabViewController" WithStoryBoard:@"Main"];
selectedTabIndex = sender.tag;//i have set tags to buttons
[tabController setSelectedTabViewItemIndex:selectedTabIndex];


-(id) getController:(NSString*) controllerIdentifier WithStoryBoard:(NSString*) storyboradName
{
    NSStoryboard *storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboradName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    return [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:controllerIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Are `tabController` and `tag` what they should be?

Comment: Show the code that sets `tabController` and the code that sets `tag`.

Comment: I have added code for setting tabview item index

Comment: What does `getController:withStoryBoard:` do?

Comment: this will return NSTabViewController object

Comment: I have just update my question. I have added getController:withStoryBoard method

Comment: Is I am creating nstableviewcontroller object wrongly

Comment: Yes, don't create a new NSTabViewController, use the existing one.

Comment: Is there any sample code link for tabless nstabviewcontroller for reference

Comment: Yes, probable there is with buttons in the toolbar. In this case the problem is getting the embedded viewcontroller.